# Example usage of GRPCcall2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grpc

In our iOS codebase, we are using `GRPCcall` to configure our connection to server. I just noticed that, in the Objective C gRPC library, the `GRPCcall` class is indicated as deprecated:

```
/**
 * This interface is deprecated. Please use \a GRPCcall2.
 *
 * Represents a single gRPC remote call.
 */
```

The comments indicate that we should use `GRPCcall2` instead. But the usage appears to be different, and based on different concepts. For example, the comments above `GRPCcall2` say

```
/**
 * Call related parameters. These parameters are automatically 
   specified by Protobuf. If directly
 * using the \a GRPCCall2 class, users should specify these parameters 
   manually.
 */
```

suggesting that users should not normally need to use this class.

At the time that this question is posted, the [gRPC Basics guide](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/objective-c/) still refers the (now deprecated) `GRPCcall` class, as does the [gRPC Object-C Quick Start guide](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/objective-c/). I can't seem to find any documentation for the new `GRPCcall2`, except for what is in the comments.

So for example, with the old class, I could do

```
GRPCCall.enableRetry(true, forHost: "bla")
```

How would I achieve that with the new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find usage examples of `GRPCCall2` in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/objective-c/tests/UnitTests/APIv2Tests.m.

The `retryEnabled` property is in [GRPCMutableCallOptions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/objective-c/GRPCClient/GRPCCallOptions.h#L284).

You could do something like this:

```
  GRPCMutableCallOptions *options = [[GRPCMutableCallOptions alloc] init];
  options.retryEnabled = YES;
  GRPCCall2 *call = [[GRPCCall2 alloc]
      initWithRequestOptions:requestOptions
      responseHandler:handler
      callOptions:options];
```

The Objective-C [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/objective-c) have also been updated to use the v2 API

Comment: The link is dead :(

Comment: I've fixed the link.